# Connecting to MySQL with Tcl

Tags: mysql, sqlite, connection, directory

I had a question about where a MySql database has to sit for a Tcl application to read it.  Currently, I have a Tcl application that reads off of a sqlite database.  For the application to find the database, the Sqlite Db must be located in the same folder as the Tcl application.   I am planning on upgrading the Sqlite Database to MySql.

Will the MySql database also have to sit in the same folder as the Tcl application?  I noticed that the connection string for MySql in Tcl doesn't require a directory path, similar to connecting to Sqlite.

Thank you,

DFM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite databases are actually only a single file *(so, your application needs to know where that file is)* ; on the other hand, MySQL is a daemon to which your application will access via a network connection *(and you're application will need to know the address of the server to which it should connect, plus DB name and login/password)*.

So, there is no such notion as "in the same directory" for a MySQL DB : you can actually put your MySQL server on a different computer/server, it'll still work the same : you will access it via a network connection.